# .Net Component for JavaScript Obfuscation?

Tags: c#, javascript, components, obfuscation

Are there any .Net components for obfuscating JavaScript? I'm generating JavaScript dynamically & emitting via ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock. I'd like to make it more difficult for others to view and modify that script.

Caveats:

- Yes, I know that JavaScript obfuscation will merely inconvenience a serious developer.
- I do intend to add (non-obfuscated) copyright notices.
- My C# program that generates the JavaScript is my real value-add. That source won't be available to viewers. Nevertheless, I'd like to obscure the functions and data that it creates.

Thanks!

Comment: Still looking... I'm seeing stand-alone GUIs that do obfusicate, and libraries that condense the code. Anything out there that does both???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the YUI Compressor for .Net. It does not obfuscate, but it do compress at least. You use it as a dll.

http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6):

You can call out to Google's Closure Compiler from .NET, here's an example:

- http://madskristensen.net/post/Use-Googles-Closure-Compiler-in-C.aspx

Or there's a .NET port of the YUI Compressor:

- http://www.codeplex.com/YUICompressor

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax Minifier mentioned above by Darin Dimitrov has been updated to include obfuscation as well as minification functionalities. It is also designed to work with your build and release process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [JS cruncher](http://www.domapi.com/jscruncherpro/features.cfm) or [stunnix](http://www.stunnix.com/prod/jo/)

Comment: I'm not seeing where either of these can be invoked programatically from a .Net program. Are these GUI-only?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Ajax Minifier](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=34488) which was recently released from Microsoft and which they use internally.

Comment: Just gave that a try. Integrates nicely w/ .Net. The "crunched" output, however, is barely different from the original. It looks to minimize whitespace characters, but doesn't even rename variables & function names to something shorter.