# Obfuscate Javascript in C# output

Tags: c#, javascript, obfuscation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net Component for JavaScript Obfuscation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880445/net-component-for-javascript-obfuscation)

Anyone know a way to obfuscate javascript before it's outputted to the browser? I was using

http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/

But I'm hoping there is a library that can do this on the fly.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Obfuscation is not compressing. I've already seen that topic.

Comment: That question is about obfuscation.  If you don't like those answers, it's not too late to add more.  This site is a wiki.  You should link relevant previous questions when asking your own.

Answer (score 0):

Related: [.Net Component for JavaScript Obfuscation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880445/net-component-for-javascript-obfuscation)

Comment: As stated above, compressing and obfuscating are totally different. Please see the link I posted for more info on what obfuscating is. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a C# library for the YUI compressor? - accepted answer for link I've posted is a .NET port of the YUI compressor.

As it is open source you could modify it to allow for turning compression on/off the same as it currently does for obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

The YUI compressor can perform obfuscation.

Comment: Is there a C# library for the YUI compressor? I was looking at this from the previous post but found nothing on it.

Comment: You would not want to be doing on-the-fly JavaScript obfuscation/compression. Better to employ a tool that does this pre- or post-build.